# MySQL-extract a number from db and use it in same query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

`table 1` in my db has many columns including `id` and `time`. an id is sent to the server, then I have to extract its corresponding time (let's say `t`) from table and run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time>t AND ...clause 1...) // query A
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time>t AND ...clause 2...) // query B
) h LIMIT 24;
```

how to include a subquery in the query mentioned above which extracts `t` and makes it accessible by query A and query B?

Comment: show to `table1` structure

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny as I mentioned in question, it has a number of columns including `id` and `time`. other columns are out of our focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need Mysql [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (Common Table Expression) here,

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE time>t
)

SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM CTE AND ...clause 1...) // query A
UNION
 (SELECT * FROM CTE AND ...clause 2...) // query B
) h LIMIT 24;
```

Comment: thanks. but the question is the value of `t` is also unknown and must be queried from table. how?!

Comment: you mentioned a good hint actually! I used the following WITH clause which solved my issue: `WITH x AS (SELECT a.* from table1 a INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '...') s ON (a.timestamp > s.timestamp))`

Comment: @Soheil glad it helps you somehow.

Comment: Caution: `WITH` requires MySQL 8.0.